# Error 5941 The requested member of the collection does not exist

Tags: vba, ms-word

Good day! So its quiet a simple logic i want to add a picture as a default background for different sections. Like A3 portrait format has one, Landscape another, and so on.  I keep on getting the 5941 Error in the code section below. Apologies for the code arrangement as it keeps on formatting it.

```
    Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks
    Dim objDocument As Document
    Dim objSection As Section  
     For i = 1 To Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) Step 1
      Set objDocument = ActiveDocument
      For Each objSection In objDocument.Sections
        With objSection.PageSetup
         If .Orientation = wdOrientPortrait Then
         'A4 portrait
           If .PageHeight > CentimetersToPoints(22) And .PageHeight < CentimetersToPoints(30) And .PageWidth < CentimetersToPoints(30) Then
               'In this portion, below, my code is highlighted. however if I change i to any digit, it seems working just fine. I want it to an iteration but FOR loop does not work, where did i go wrong?
             Set MyImage1 = **ThisDocument.Sections(i)**.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary) _
               .Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(ImagePath1).ConvertToShape 
               MyImage1.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind
               With MyImage1 
              .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
              .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
              .Top = wdShapeTop
              .Left = wdShapeLeft
              .Height = CentimetersToPoints(29.7)
              .Width = CentimetersToPoints(21)
 End With
    'A3 portret
           ElseIf .PageHeight > CentimetersToPoints(30) And .PageWidth < CentimetersToPoints(30) Then
              Set MyImage7 = ThisDocument.Sections(i).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary) _
             .Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(ImagePath7).ConvertToShape
             MyImage7.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind
             With MyImage7
            .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
            .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
            .Top = wdShapeTop
            .Left = wdShapeLeft
            .Height = CentimetersToPoints(42)
            .Width = CentimetersToPoints(29.7)
          End With
            ElseIf .Orientation = wdOrientLandscape Then
    ' A4 landscape
             ElseIf .PageHeight < CentimetersToPoints(22) And .PageWidth < CentimetersToPoints(30) Then
              Set MyImage3 = ThisDocument.Sections(i).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary) _
             .Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(ImagePath3).ConvertToShape
              MyImage3.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind
                With MyImage3
                 .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
                 .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
                 .Top = wdShapeTop
                 .Left = wdShapeLeft
                 .Height = CentimetersToPoints(21)
                 .Width = CentimetersToPoints(29.7)
                  End With
    'A3 landscape
           ElseIf .PageHeight > CentimetersToPoints(30) And .PageWidth > CentimetersToPoints(30) Then
                Set MyImage6 = ThisDocument.Sections(i).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary) _
               .Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(ImagePath6).ConvertToShape
                MyImage6.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind
             With MyImage6
                  .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
                  .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
                  .Top = wdShapeTop
                  .Left = wdShapeLeft
                  .Height = CentimetersToPoints(29.7)
                  .Width = CentimetersToPoints(42)
    End With
    End If
    End If
    End With
    Next
    Next
```

Comment: Which line of code exactly gives the error?

Comment: Set MyImage1 = **ThisDocument.Sections(i)**.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary) _
               .Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(ImagePath1).ConvertToShape---- In the bold figures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems rather confused and contains several undeclared variables.

1. You start off with a loop stepping though a counter of the pages in
   the selection. This is unnecessary and should be removed because
   there is no connection between the number of pages and the number of
   sections in a document.
2. You are setting `objDocument` within the initial loop. This means
   that `objDocument` is reset at each pass through the loop. `Set
   objDocument = ActiveDocument` should be moved to the beginning of
   your code before the loop begins.
3. You then loop through the sections in objDocument. This is the only
   loop you need in your code.
4. When you come to adding the image you suddenly switch from
   `objDocument` to `ThisDocument`. Depending on where the code modules
   are located `ThisDocument` may not be the same document as
   `objDocument`.
5. You then introduce a further potential source of error with
   `ThisDocument.Sections(i)`. As the counter you are using is not
   related to the number of sections it is highly likely that
   `ThisDocument.Sections(i)` doesn't exist. You should replace this
   with `objSection`.

Comment: It has worked! Thank you. Have still some problems with determining which layout I'm looking at, but its manageable. Thank you once again!